# Excel:In a table with two columns (item,quantity) finding out the name of the item with the largest quantity

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel and I came across this problem. 
I have a table with 2 columns one with the name of the item(the same name can appear multiple times) and next to it the quantity of said item. 
What I want to get is the item which has the most overll quantity (keeping in mind that the object can appear multiple times in the table and have different quantities in each of the apppearences).

Comment: The largest individual qty or the the largest sumif qty (total qty for one item on multiple lines).

Comment: This question needs sample data together with expected results (in a code block, not an image).

Comment: Sample data is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you want to highlight the value.

[image: example]

Assuming your items are in column A and your values in column B.

Add a helper formula in column C to sum all the items.

`=SUMIF($A$1:$A$100,A1,$B$1:$B$100)`

you can use conditional formatting to highlight the highest value by adding a rule that uses a formula and entering;

`=B1=MAX($C$1:$C$100)`

It highlights every entry of the item with the greatest value.

To return the name of the item with the highest value you can use;

`=INDEX(A1:A100,MATCH(MAX(C1:C100),C1:C100,0),1)`

There are 2 parts to this formula

=INDEX(A1:A100,**MATCH(MAX(C1:C100),C1:C100,0)**,1)

The match part finds the row number of the highest value and the Index part returns the value in column A for that row.

This solution may not be ideal if you have a huge amount of data so you could also try a pivot table and sort it highest to lowest.